# How could I solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pheweb.command_line'"

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to run a software called 'Pheweb' on Ubuntu.
I followed the [guideline here](https://github.com/statgen/pheweb)
but got `'permission denied'` error when I ran `'pip3 install pheweb'`. So I installed with this code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev libz-dev libffi-dev
sudo python3 -m pip install wheel cython
sudo python3 -m pip install pheweb
```

as the guideline author suggests in the `'detailed install instructions'`.

I wanted to check that it's properly installed by typing `'pheweb --help'`
but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pheweb", line 5, in <module>
    from pheweb.command_line import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pheweb.command_line'
```

**This is what else I've tried:**

1. The author states the below proceedure in 'the detailed install instructions' and I tried this but still got the same error;

If installation was successful but the command pheweb --help is not found,
you need to add pheweb to your PATH. You should be able to just run

```
echo'PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

, start a new terminal, and try pheweb --help again.

2. When I run this code:

```
sudo python3 -m pip show pheweb
```

I get this result:

```
Name: PheWeb
Version: 1.3.16
Summary: A tool for building PheWAS websites from association files
Home-page: <https://github.com/statgen/pheweb>
Author: Peter VandeHaar
Author-email: pjvh@umich.edu
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: boltons, cffi, Flask, Flask-Compress, Flask-Login, gevent, gunicorn, intervaltree, numpy, psutil, pysam, rauth, requests, scipy, tqdm, wget
```

I tried adding

```
PATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:$PATH"
```

to `~/.bashrc` as well but I still got the same error.

When I run `which pheweb`
The result is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/pheweb
```

How could I solve this problem?